# How can I input specific arguments to argparse?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, argparse

I found this code on the web that can parse a specific type of text file as below:

```
# RELION; version 3.0

data_images

loop_ 
_rlnCoordinateX #1 
_rlnCoordinateY #2 
_rlnHelicalTubeID #3 
_rlnAngleTiltPrior #4 
_rlnAnglePsiPrior #5 
_rlnHelicalTrackLength #6 
_rlnAnglePsiFlipRatio #7 
_rlnImageName #8 
_rlnMicrographName #9 
_rlnMagnification #10 
_rlnDetectorPixelSize #11 
_rlnCtfMaxResolution #12 
_rlnCtfFigureOfMerit #13 
_rlnVoltage #14 
_rlnDefocusU #15 
_rlnDefocusV #16 
_rlnDefocusAngle #17 
_rlnSphericalAberration #18 
_rlnCtfBfactor #19 
_rlnCtfScalefactor #20 
_rlnPhaseShift #21 
_rlnAmplitudeContrast #22 
_rlnOriginX #23 
_rlnOriginY #24 
 3041.398896  3692.419723            1    90.000000    63.534898     0.000000     0.500000 000001@Extract/job011/Movies/Microtubules_02563.mrcs MotionCorr/job003/Movies/Microtubules_02563.mrc 10000.000000     5.480000     5.830000     0.124704   300.000000  7457.819824  6964.129883    33.520000     2.700000     0.000000     1.000000     0.000000     0.100000     0.031176 2.475269e-32 
 3068.235643  3638.511334            1    90.000000    63.534898    60.218978     0.500000 000002@Extract/job011/Movies/Microtubules_02563.mrcs MotionCorr/job003/Movies/Microtubules_02563.mrc 10000.000000     5.480000     5.830000     0.124704   300.000000  7457.819824  6964.129883    33.520000     2.700000     0.000000     1.000000     0.000000     0.100000     0.000000     0.000000 
 3095.072390  3584.602946            1    90.000000    63.534898   120.437956     0.500000 000003@Extract/job011/Movies/Microtubules_02563.mrcs MotionCorr/job003/Movies/Microtubules_02563.mrc 10000.000000     5.480000     5.830000     0.124704   300.000000  7457.819824  6964.129883    33.520000     2.700000     0.000000     1.000000     0.000000     0.100000     0.000000     0.000000 
 3121.909136  3530.694558            1    90.000000    63.534898   180.656934     0.500000 000004@Extract/job011/Movies/Microtubules_02563.mrcs MotionCorr/job003/Movies/Microtubules_02563.mrc 10000.000000     5.480000     5.830000     0.124704   300.000000  7457.819824  6964.129883    33.520000     2.700000     0.000000     1.000000     0.000000     0.100000     0.000000     0.000000
```

The code (two classes and a few lines at the end to call them):

```
import os
import sys
import argparse
from collections import OrderedDict, namedtuple


class Column:
    def __init__(self, name, type=None):
        self._name = name
        # Get the type from the LABELS dict, assume str by default
        self._type = type

    def __str__(self):
        return self._name

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return self._name == str(other)


class Table:
    """
    Class to hold and manipulate tabular data for EM processing programs.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.clear()

        if 'fileName' in kwargs:
            if 'columns' in kwargs:
                raise Exception("Please provide either 'columns' or 'fileName',"
                                " but not both.")
            fileName = kwargs.get('fileName')
            tableName = kwargs.get('tableName', None)
            self.read(fileName, tableName)
        elif 'columns' in kwargs:
            self._createColums(kwargs['columns'])

    def clear(self):
        self.Row = None
        self._columns = OrderedDict()
        self._rows = []

    def clearRows(self):
        """ Remove all the rows from the table, but keep its columns. """
        self._rows = []

    def addRow(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._rows.append(self.Row(*args, **kwargs))

    def readStar(self, inputFile, tableName=None):
        """
        :param inputFile: Provide the input file from where to read the data.
            The file pointer will be moved until the last data line of the
            requested table.
        :return:
        """
        self.clear()
        dataStr = 'data_%s' % (tableName or '')

        self._findDataLine(inputFile, dataStr)

        # Find first column line and parse all columns
        line, foundLoop = self._findLabelLine(inputFile)
        colNames = []
        values = []

        while line.startswith('_'):
            parts = line.split()
            colNames.append(parts[0][1:])
            if not foundLoop:
                values.append(parts[1])
            line = inputFile.readline().strip()

        self._createColums(colNames)

        if not foundLoop:
            self.addRow(*values)
        else:
            # Parse all data lines
            while line:
                self.addRow(*line.split())
                line = inputFile.readline().strip()

    def read(self, fileName, tableName=None):
        with open(fileName) as f:
            self.readStar(f, tableName)

    def writeStar(self, outputFile, tableName=None, singleRow=False):
        """
        Write a Table in Star format to the given file.
        :param outputFile: File handler that should be already opened and
            in the position to write.
        :param tableName: The name of the table to write.
        :param singleRow: If True, don't write loop_, just label - value pairs.
        """
        outputFile.write("\ndata_%s\n\n" % (tableName or ''))

        if self.size() == 0:
            return

        if singleRow:
            m = max([len(c) for c in self._columns.keys()]) + 5
            lineFormat = "_{:<%d} {:>10}\n" % m
            row = self._rows[0]
            for col, value in row._asdict().iteritems():
                outputFile.write(lineFormat.format(col, value))
            outputFile.write('\n\n')
            return

        outputFile.write("loop_\n")

        # Write column names
        for col in self._columns.values():
            outputFile.write("_%s \n" % col)

        # Take a hint for the columns width from the first row

        widths = [len(str(v)) for v in self._rows[0]]
        # Check middle and last row, just in case ;)
        for index in [len(self)//2, -1]:
            for i, v in enumerate(self._rows[index]):
                w = len(str(v))
                if w > widths[i]:
                    widths[i] = w

        lineFormat = " ".join("{:>%d} " % (w + 1) for w in widths)

        # Write data rows
        for row in self._rows:
            outputFile.write(lineFormat.format(*row))
            outputFile.write('\n')

        outputFile.write('\n')

    def write(self, output_star, tableName=None):
        with open(output_star, 'w') as output_file:
            self.writeStar(output_file, tableName)

    def printStar(self, tableName=None):
        self.writeStar(sys.stdout, tableName)

    def size(self):
        return len(self._rows)

    def getColumns(self):
        return self._columns.values()

    def getColumnValues(self, colName):
        """
        Return the values of a given column
        :param colName: The name of an existing column to retrieve values.
        :return: A list with all values of that column.
        """
        if colName not in self._columns:
            raise Exception("Not existing column: %s" % colName)
        return [getattr(row, colName) for row in self._rows]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size()

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self._rows:
            yield item

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._rows[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._rows[key] = value

    # --------- Internal implementation methods ------------------------

    def _addColumn(self, nameOrTuple):
        """
        :param nameOrTuple: This parameter should be either a string or
            a tuple (string, type).
        """
        if isinstance(nameOrTuple, str):
            col = Column(nameOrTuple)
        elif isinstance(nameOrTuple, tuple):
            col = Column(nameOrTuple[0], nameOrTuple[1])
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid input as column, "
                            "should be either string or tuple.")
        self._columns[str(col)] = col

    def _createColums(self, columnList):
        self.clear()
        for col in columnList:
            self._addColumn(col)
        self._createRowClass()

    def _createRowClass(self):
        self.Row = namedtuple('Row', [str(c) for c in self._columns])

    def _findDataLine(self, inputFile, dataStr):
        """ Raise an exception if the desired data string is not found.
        Move the line pointer after the desired line if found.
        """
        line = inputFile.readline()
        while line:
            if line.startswith(dataStr):
                return line
            line = inputFile.readline()

        raise Exception("%s block was not found")

    def _findLabelLine(self, inputFile):
        line = ''
        foundLoop = False

        l = inputFile.readline()
        while l:
            if l.startswith('_'):
                line = l
                break
            elif l.startswith('loop_'):
                foundLoop = True
            l = inputFile.readline()

        return line.strip(), foundLoop




if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Script to manipulate metadata files.")

    add = parser.add_argument  # shortcut
    add("input", help="Input metadata filename. ", nargs='?', default="")
    add("output",
        help="Output metadata filename, if no provided, print to stdout. ",
        nargs='?', default="")

    add("-l", "--limit", type=int, default=0,
        help="Limit the number of rows processed, useful for testing. ")

    #add("-v", "--verbosity", action="count", default=0)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if '@' in args.input:
        tableName, fileName = args.input.split('@')
    else:
        tableName, fileName = None, args.input

    if not os.path.exists(fileName):
        raise Exception("Input file '%s' does not exists. " % fileName)

    tableIn = Table(fileName=fileName, tableName=tableName)




    # Create another table with same columns
    tableOut = Table(columns=[str(c) for c in tableIn.getColumns()])

    limit = args.limit

    for i, row in enumerate(tableIn):
        if limit > 0 and i == limit:
            break

        tableOut.addRow(*row)

    if args.output:
        tableOut.write(args.output, tableName)
    else:
        tableOut.printStar(tableName)
```

The problem and a few questions: I want to use this code to change the value of a certain column and rewrite the above text file (P.s. this is a trivial python script, but I want to accomplish this task using the object oriented code above).

I also have a few questions about this code. The only argument I provide to this script is the text file, but I see this line here if args.output:tableOut.write(args.output, tableName) which implies that other arguments are possible, which would result in rewriting the file, instead of just printing it as the code would execute if you would just run it on the above text file. Also if '@' in args.input:, what is the purpose of this conditional, why would I input @ in the arguments for this script?! (the code doesn't come with documentation)

My attempt at the solution (since I don't practice object oriented python a lot): I thought perhaps I can add this function to the Table class and then add the following line to the final script to change a certain column value to the input values from the user.

```
    def _changeColumnsValue(self, colName, colValue):
        if colName not in self._columns:
            raise Exception("Not existing column: %s" % colName)
        for row in self._rows:
            setattr(row, colName, colValue) 


    change_value  = input('Which column would you like to change, and to what value? Example input: _rlnVoltage 200')
    tableOut._changeColumnsValue(change_value.split()[0], change_value.split()[1])
```

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! please [edit] your post to cut down on unneeded code. please see [mre] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The help for the `parser` (can get with '-h'):

```
In [3]: parser.print_help()                                                                      
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-l LIMIT] [input] [output]

Script to manipulate metadata files.

positional arguments:
  input                 Input metadata filename.
  output                Output metadata filename, if no provided, print to
                        stdout.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -l LIMIT, --limit LIMIT
                        Limit the number of rows processed, useful for
                        testing.
```

If no arguments, both `args.input` and `args.output` get their default value, an empty string.

In one string is given it is assigned to `input`; if two strings, the second is assigned to `output`.

That's about it for the `argparse` part.

As for the `@` apparently you can specify two strings:

```
tableName@fileName
filename
```

I'm guessing you'll get the `Input file '%s' does not exists` error if you don't provide a `input` string.

The meaning of these is up to the `Table` function.

```
if args.output:
    tableOut.write(args.output, tableName)
else:
    tableOut.printStar(tableName)
```

If `output`isn't the default, "", pass that string to `write`, otherwise use `printStar`.

I can imagine adding the `change_value` argument to the `parser`

```
add('--change_value', nargs=2, help='column and value that you want to change')
```

and later

```
if args.change_value is not None:
      col_name, col_value = args.change_value
      tableOut._changeColumnsValue(col_name, col_value)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I do have another question. Since it's not very clear what the purpose of this script is, I wonder if it is possible to call some of the Table methods on the input file to get some useful output out of this script. I assume it's going to be through argparse as you explained, but is there another way? also can you give one more example of using argparse if possible.

Comment: If you `import` the module it will load the two classes, `Column` and `Table`.  `Table` can then be called from your own script just as it is done in the section that uses `argparse`.  In fact, to explore the code, I'd open an interactive python session, import the module, and experiment with calls to `Table`, etc.  The `argparse` part is just a way of specifying these file and table names.  I have't tried to figure out what `Table` does.